# How to connect java code with database without using any jar files?

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

Can I connect java code with database without using jar files?

I want to write java code which will not be dependent on odbc6.jar files to connect with database. Is it possible?

Comment: Usualy the *jdbc driver* is used to connect to database.

Comment: *"Is it possible?"* - Perhaps, but please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269359/2144390) to understand why you may never receive a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to connect to an Oracle DB without depending on the jar file which contains the jdbc driver.

1. Extract the files out of the jar using: `jar xf odbc6.jar`
2. Implement your own jdbc driver, in effect writing your own version of the jdbc driver for oracle.